# Aspectj project does not compile on terminal while it compiles in Eclipse

Tags: inheritance, command-line, compiler-errors, aspectj

I am new at using aspectj and I am very sorry if this is a very simple question. But I could not solve the problem even after a days-long internet search. I have an aspectj project created using Eclipse. It perfectly runs and compiles in Eclipse. I am also able to create a valid runnable jar via Eclipse.
Unfortunately, I can not compile the same project on command-line. Here is the compilation errors:

```
egeyar@paris:~/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello$ ajc World.aj HelloWorld.java 
/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:75 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Object  
objList[i]=list[i]; //copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:85 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:96 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:107 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from short to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:118 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:129 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from float to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:140 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

/home/egeyar/workspace/FirstAspectJProject/src/hello/World.aj:151 [error] Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Object  
objList[i]=list[i];//copy to object list in order to use Arrays.deepToString
           ^^

8 errors
```

I would be glad if anyone could give me at least a hint. what could be the reason of accepting the code in eclipse but not on command-line? is it a class-path error (which I know nothing about), or would it be because of some compiler version problem, etc.

Comment: Can you please provide source code (maybe a download link if it is too big to quote here, but a minimal failing example would be better) and information about the AspectJ compiler versions used in Eclipse and on command line? The Eclipse settings for the AspectJ compiler would also be of interest. Then maybe someone can reproduce it and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using different compilers in eclipse and on the system(bash).

Also the compile error talks about type mismatch which means the wrong class of object 
was accepted by the method.

There are several solutions depending on your code but if it compiles in eclipse just use it.

aspectJ documentation suggests no to use .aj if you don't have to so I would try to change the extension too.

and this 
[bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384398)